# Use JS library xml2js with Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, typescript, angular

I´m trying to use xml2js as XML parser within an Angular 2 (RC 1 with TypeScript) webapplication. However I only get some errors and no working solution.

Here is what I did step by step:

- installed xml2js via `npm install xml2js`
- installed according d.ts-file via `tsd install xml2js`
- included script link to my index.html: `<script src="../node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js"></script>`
- configured SystemJS by adding `'xml2js': '../node_modules/xml2js'` to map and `'xml2js': { defaultExtension: 'js' }` to packages
- import Parser of xml2js in my component via `import {Parser} from 'xml2js';`
- try using it in constructor of component:
  `var parser = new Parser();
   var xml = "<root>Hello xml2js!</root>"
   parser.parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
      console.dir(result);
  });`

This is what browser console tells me when opening a webpage containing the component:

> module.js:440 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'sax'

and

> GET file:///C:/xxx/source/node_modules/xml2js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

as well as

> index.html:17 Error: Error: XHR error loading file:///C:/xxx/source/node_modules/xml2js
>           at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (file:///C:/xxx/source/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:38)
>           at Zone.runTask (file:///C:/xxx/source/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:48)
>           at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (file:///C:/xxx/source/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:423:34)
>       Error loading file:///C:/xxx/source/node_modules/xml2js as "xml2js" from file:///C:/xxx/source/frontend/angular/components/mycomponent/mycomponent.js

"sax" is located in `node_modules/xml2js/node_modules/sax` as installed via npm.
What did I miss installing the external library? Is there a "better" way to use external JS libraries with Angular 2 & TypeScript?

Comment: Same. Eventually it complained it can't find "events" or "timers" and had no idea how to deal with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way.

You can use `System.set('xml2js', System.newModule(require('xml2js')))` to load your local xml2js module in systemjs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a great working, simple solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I try this, I see in the console a ReferenceError: Can't find variable require.

Comment: @sss4r Sorry, I don't know why it occurs. Too less information.

Comment: @sss4r I googled it and found it looks like a common issue, lots of github issues were talking about this question. Maybe you can find your answer there.